# Swift Combine - Does the zip operator retain all values that it hasn't had a chance to publish?

Tags: memory-leaks, timer, zip, combine, publisher

Here's the code I'm wondering about:

```
final class Foo {
    
    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init () {
        Timer
            .publish(every: 2, on: .main, in: .default)
            .autoconnect()
            .zip(Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect())
            .sink {
                print($0)
            }
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}
```

This is the output it produces:

```
(2020-12-08 15:45:41 +0000, 2020-12-08 15:45:42 +0000)
(2020-12-08 15:45:43 +0000, 2020-12-08 15:45:45 +0000)
(2020-12-08 15:45:45 +0000, 2020-12-08 15:45:48 +0000)
(2020-12-08 15:45:47 +0000, 2020-12-08 15:45:51 +0000)
```

Would this code eventually crash from memory shortage? It seems like the zip operator is storing every value that it receives but can't yet publish.

Comment: I'd say your assumption is true - Zip will hold an increasing number of values of the faster timer.

Comment: Of course, it would take a very long time to accumulate enough to crash the app. Every 6 seconds it holds an extra Date object. Not sure how large the Date object is, but if it's, say 8 bytes, then to get to 100M it would take about 900 days (if I calculated it correctly)

Answer (score 0):

`zip` does **not** limit its upstream buffer size. You can prove it like this:

```
import Combine

let ticket = (0 ... .max).publisher
    .zip(Empty<Int, Never>(completeImmediately: false))
    .sink { print($0) }
```

The `(0 ... .max)` publisher will try to publish 2<sup>63</sup> values synchronously (that, is, before returning control to the `Zip` subscriber). Run this and watch the memory gauge in Xcode's Debug navigator. It will climb steadily. You probably want to kill it after a few seconds, because it will eventually use up an awful lot of memory and make your Mac unpleasant to use before finally crashing.

If you run it in Instruments for a few seconds, you'll see that all of the allocations happen in this call stack, indicating that `Zip` internally uses a plain old `Array` to buffer the incoming values.

```
  66.07 MB      99.8%   174      main
  64.00 MB      96.7%   45        Publisher<>.sink(receiveValue:)
  64.00 MB      96.7%   42         Publisher.subscribe<A>(_:)
  64.00 MB      96.7%   41          Publishers.Zip.receive<A>(subscriber:)
  64.00 MB      96.7%   12           Publisher.subscribe<A>(_:)
  64.00 MB      96.7%   2             Empty.receive<A>(subscriber:)
  64.00 MB      96.7%   2              AbstractZip.Side.receive(subscription:)
  64.00 MB      96.7%   2               AbstractZip.receive(subscription:index:)
  64.00 MB      96.7%   2                AbstractZip.resolvePendingDemandAndUnlock()
  64.00 MB      96.7%   2                 protocol witness for Subscription.request(_:) in conformance Publishers.Sequence<A, B>.Inner<A1, B1, C1>
  64.00 MB      96.7%   2                  Publishers.Sequence.Inner.request(_:)
  64.00 MB      96.7%   1                   AbstractZip.Side.receive(_:)
  64.00 MB      96.7%   1                    AbstractZip.receive(_:index:)
  64.00 MB      96.7%   1                     specialized Array._copyToNewBuffer(oldCount:)
  64.00 MB      96.7%   1                      specialized _ArrayBufferProtocol._forceCreateUniqueMutableBufferImpl(countForBuffer:minNewCapacity:requiredCapacity:)
  64.00 MB      96.7%   1                       swift_allocObject
  64.00 MB      96.7%   1                        swift_slowAlloc
  64.00 MB      96.7%   1                         malloc
  64.00 MB      96.7%   1                          malloc_zone_malloc
```